# Debug Google AppEngine localhost from different Machine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm using eclipse to debug a google app engine app. I'd like to connect to the GAE App running on Eclipse on my laptop from my iPhone.

In eclipse I tried Run->Debug Configurations and then adding an --address option to use my IP address

[image]

But I must not be doing it right because I get this error when I try to debug

[Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Usage:  [options]

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, found this post and was able to solve with your tips.  Thanks

First, don't add the --address at the end of the argument list or the war path gets auto added twice to the arguments (see in your screen shot that you have an extra /Users/arc/Documents/workspace/jsoup/war added after the --address

Second.  The --address doesn't seem to work for me on Linux Mint and Eclipse Junu.  I had to use -a

So my argument list looks like:

-a 0.0.0.0 --port=8080 /home/d/workspace/blah/war

Answer (score 0):

Setting the IP address to 0.0.0.0 should get it working.. (I don't know how to successfully do that in Eclipse)

Comment: Yeah 0.0.0.0 gives the same error. Hopefully someone knows eclipse can clarify...

Answer (score 0):

Add `-bindAddress *localIPaddress*` just before `-port` argument. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking into this who are using IntelliJ you need to go to Edit Configurations. Under your AppEngine Dev Server you'll find a page where you can set "Server parameters". Set this to:

```
--address=[ip address]
```

for example

```
--address=192.168.1.115
```